# The component is not wrapped

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to figure out what is the problem here. I keep getting the same error message which is "Error: could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a < Provider >".

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import '../styles/global.css';
import Router from 'next/router';
import ProgressBar from "@badrap/bar-of-progress";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import { useDispatch, useSelector, Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from '../src/app/store'
import { login, logout, selectUser } from "./userSlice";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

    const user = useSelector(selectUser);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {

      const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(userAuth => {
        if(userAuth) {
          dispatch(
            login({
            uid: userAuth.uid,
            email: userAuth.email
          })
          );
        } else {
          dispatch(logout);
        }
      });
      return unsubscribe;
    }, []);

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Component {...pageProps}/>
      </Provider>
    )

}

export default MyApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyApp is not inside the `<Provider store={store}>` that's why it can't get value from `useSelector`. The `Provider` Component is what allows it's children to get and set values to the Redux store.

So you must lift up your provider above `<MyApp />` Component for Redux like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
   <MyApp />
</Provider>
```